# Determine treatment effect based on conditional factors

Tags: predictive-models, causality

Say I have an experiment running where I give treatment to a random selection of people, and I know that the target variable is affected by a number of factors. I know most of the factors that affect the target. So with this, I can run a model on my data, predict the target variable and see if the treatment variable is picked up by the model. (let's say lin. reg. for simplicity)

I want to predict what the magnitude of a treatment effect depending some of the factors that affect the target. So maybe the treatment effect declines with subject age, or income bracket. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can estimate a regression specification with all these on the right hand side:

1. a treatment indicator variable $t$
2. the covariates that influence the target, $x$s
3. interactions between treatment indicator and each covariate where you expect to see heterogeneity in the treatment effect.

Say you had one covariate $x$:

$$E[ y \vert x, t] = \alpha + \beta x + \gamma t + \eta t \cdot x.$$

The effect of treatment is then
$$ \frac{\partial E[ y \vert x, t]}{\partial t}= \gamma + \eta x,$$

which is a function of $x$. You can evaluate that at the typical $x$ or plot a curve for the range of the values that you see in the data. You can also just consider the coefficient $\eta$, which tells you whether $x$ alters the treatment effect $\beta$.

If you have lots of covariates, then some more sophisticated methods can be used to model the heterogeneity.

Comment: Awesome! How are the sophisticated methods called? Any keywords I can google to go deeper into this subject? For instance, how would you do this when the target variable is binary, or multiple classes?

Comment: @PeterSmit You can either do regularization (where you shrink some of the interaction coefficients) or you can use [causal forests](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.04342). These both require substantial data to allow for more model complexity.